# Unable to kill a process (Prometheus) listening on port 9090 keeps restarting

Tags: linux, command-line, port, kill

I was using a tool called Prometheus to monitor containers on my VM. Now I want to remove it but it seems impossible.

```sh
nima@caliper-latest:~/caliper$ sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:9090
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
prometheu 10171 prometheus    5u  IPv4 127446      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45670->127.0.0.1:9090 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10171 prometheus    7u  IPv4 132766      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45674->127.0.0.1:9090 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10171 prometheus    8u  IPv6 133455      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9090->127.0.0.1:45674 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10171 prometheus   10u  IPv6 133453      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9090->127.0.0.1:45670 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then I kill the PID and check immideatly and it is up on another process again:

```sh
nima@caliper-latest:~/caliper$ sudo kill -9 10171
nima@caliper-latest:~/caliper$ sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:9090
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
prometheu 10428 prometheus    5u  IPv4 128485      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45776->127.0.0.1:9090 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10428 prometheus    7u  IPv4 132877      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45778->127.0.0.1:9090 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10428 prometheus    8u  IPv6 132878      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9090->127.0.0.1:45778 (ESTABLISHED)
prometheu 10428 prometheus   11u  IPv6 134235      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9090->127.0.0.1:45776 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I tried other commands like killall etc. but no luck. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: “Any idea how to get rid of this?” Why not try normal methods of stopping and disabling services? How that’ll work depends in which init system you have.

Comment: Or just uninstall it? Depends on your Linux system - it could be as simple as `sudo apt remove software` or depends on your actual package manager (or your installation method).

Comment: The problem was solved by "sudo apt remove prometheus" and "sudo apt remove prometheus-node-exporter"

Answer (score 0):

As said  by @DanielB, you **must** use your system mechanisms to stop or start a service.

Under Linux, sysvinit style, calling `/etc/init.d/prometheus stop` is the offical, correct way to stop a service.
Under Linux, systemd style, the `/etc/init.d/prometheus stop` may also be implemented. If not, you will have to use `systemctl stop <the service name>`.

I guess that your system is using `systemd` since respawning a killed process isn't implemented in sysvinit ...